# Redirect old URLs to new ones in multidomain setup

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how can I redirect old URLs to new ones using htaccess in a multidomain setup.

I know I can write something like

```
Redirect 301 /old.html http://example.com/new.html
```

But what if I have multiple domains using the same htaccess and may have some same named sites. E.g.

```
http://example.com/old.html -> http://example.com/new.html
http://othersite.com/old.html -> http://othersite.com/new.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple domains, you need to use mod-rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ http://domain.com/newpage.html [L,R,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2.com$
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ http://domain.com/newpage.html [L,R,NC]
```